# Endomorphism of Jacobian of hyperelliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $C$ be a hyperelliptic curve of genus $g=2＞1$, given by an equation, $u^2=1-4t+2t^2-6t^3+t^4+2t^5+t^6$.
Let $J(C)$ be a Jacobian of $C$.

Why $End_ \Bbb{Q}(J(C)) \cong  \Bbb{Z}[(-1+ \sqrt{5})/2]$ holds ?

$J(C)$ cannot be expressed as equation explicitly, so I don't have way to check this. Once equation is explicitly given, I will be able to find element of $End _\Bbb{Q}(J(C))- \Bbb{Z}$, but I cannot do this in this situation, so at a loss.

Comment: $\frac{-1+\sqrt{-5}}{2}$ isn’t an algebraic integer, so the result you’re quoting is false. Why did you think it was true in the first place?

Comment: Sorry, it was typo. I modified. I found this in an article written by Sairaiji without explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I modified typos.

Comment: Not sure how much it helps, but there is only one genus $2$ curve in the LMFDB with bad reduction controlled by the discriminant of this equation (at $2,13,17$) and such an endomorphism ring. It’s $48841.a.48841.1$. But the Weierstrass equations aren’t the same…

Comment: @Aphelli Good find! I checked using Magma and the OP's curve and [48841.a.48841.1](https://www.lmfdb.org/Genus2Curve/Q/48841/a/48841/1) are indeed isomorphic over $\mathbb{Q}$. An isomorphism is $[X:Y:Z] \mapsto [-Z:-(1/2)X^3 + (1/2)X^2 Z + (1/2)Y + (1/2)Z^3 : X]$.

Comment: @VictorVaughn: Wow, this isomorphism was not trivial to find by any means… so that answers the OP’s specific question. But I wonder – what if there was no table? How would one go about determining the endomorphism ring of the Jacobian from just the equation of the curve?

Comment: @Aphelli There are also Magma commands to compute the endomorphism ring of the Jacobian of a genus 2 curve. I don't know their inner workings in detail, but I may try to add an answer later with at least the calculations. I'm also not sure if Magma's results are provably corrrect (they use period matrices, so depend on complex numbers with numberical precision), but there are some algorithms that are: [Lombardo](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09674) and [Costa et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09248).

Comment: @Aphelli  Why $End(J(C)) \cong  \Bbb{Z}[α]$'s $ \alpha$ is algebraic integer ?

Comment: Because the ring of endomorphisms of an abelian variety is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module. At least in characteristic zero (look at the complex uniformization). @ViktorVaughn: thank you for the references, they look interesting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g=2$ and let $J$ be the Jacobian of $C$. The complex points of an abelian variety form a complex torus, so $\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}} \newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}} J(\C) \cong \C^g/\Lambda$ where $\Lambda \leq \C^g$ is the period lattice of $C$. An endomorphism $\varphi: J \to J$ induces an endomorphism $\varphi^*: \C^g/\Lambda \to \C^g/\Lambda$, which is really just a linear map $\varphi^*: \C^g \to \C^g$ such that $\varphi^*(\Lambda) \subseteq \Lambda$. Thus, to find all endomorphisms of the abelian variety $J$, we first find all endomorphisms of the torus $J(\C)$ and then check that these come from endomorphisms of the abelian variety $J$.

Choose a basis $\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_g$ for $H^0(C, \Omega_C)$ and a basis $\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_{2g}$ for $H_1(J(\C), \Z)$. Let $\Pi$ be the $g \times 2g$ period matrix with respect to these bases, so
$$
\displaystyle
\Pi =
\left(
\int_{\gamma_i} \omega_j
\right)_{\substack{i = 1, \ldots, 2g\\ j = 1, \ldots, g}}
$$
and $\Lambda = \Pi \Z^{2g}$. Then the linear map $\varphi^*$ with $\varphi^*(\Lambda) \subseteq \Lambda$ is given by multiplication by a $g \times g$ matrix $M$ such that
$$
M \Pi = \Pi R
$$
for some $2g \times 2g$ matrix $R$. (Since $\varphi^*(\Lambda) \subseteq \Lambda$, then $M \Pi$ must be a linear combination of the columns of $\Pi$; the coefficients in these linear combinations are given by $R$.) Such matrices $M$ can be found using numerical linear algebra. (The entries of the period matrix are complex numbers, hence can only be represented up to some numerical precision.)

These ideas have been implemented in *Magma*; here is some code for your example.

```
R<x> := PolynomialRing(QQ);
f := 1-4*x+2*x^2-6*x^3+x^4+2*x^5+x^6;
C := HyperellipticCurve(f);
J := AnalyticJacobian(C);
E := EndomorphismRing(J);
R!MinimalPolynomial(E.1);
```

The matrix `E.1` generating the endomorphism ring is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
  0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
  0 & -1 & 1 & 0\\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and the above code returns $x^2 - x - 1$ as its minimal polynomial, which is the minimal polynomial for $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. (You can try the code yourself at the [online *Magma* calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/).) The *Magma* implementation of the analytic Jacobian for hyperelliptic curves is described in

[van Wamelen, Paul B. "Computing with the analytic Jacobian of a genus 2 curve." *Discovering Mathematics with Magma: Reducing the Abstract to the Concrete*](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-37634-7_5).

The above calculations shows that there is an endomorphism of complex tori that acts as $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, but we still haven't rigorously shown that the endomorphism of tori comes from an endomorphism of abelian varieties. In the linked article, van Wamelen explains how this can be verified via interpolation. There are two alternative approaches to this verification step, one by Lombardo in [*Computing the geometric endomorphism ring of a genus 2 Jacobian*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09674) and another by Costa et al. in [*Rigorous computation of the endomorphism ring of a Jacobian*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09248). Both are implemented in *Magma*; Lombardo has code on [his webpage](http://people.dm.unipi.it/lombardo/Publications.php) and Costa et al.'s code is on [Github](https://github.com/edgarcosta/endomorphisms). (As a note, the methods and implementations of Costa et al. also work for curves of higher genus as well as non-hyperelliptic curves; see the examples in $\S8.2$.)

In this case, we can also verify the calculation using the LMFDB. As suggested by Aphelli in the comments, your curve $C$ is isomorphic to the hyperelliptic curve with LMFDB label [48841.a.48841.1](https://www.lmfdb.org/Genus2Curve/Q/48841/a/48841/1) which has simplified equation
$$
C': y^2 = x^6 + 4x^5 + 2x^4 + 6x^3 + x^2 - 2x + 1 \, .
$$
Computing with *Magma*, we find the isomorphism
\begin{align*}
C &\overset{\sim}{\to} C'\\
(X : Y : Z) &\mapsto (-Z : (-1/2)X^3 + (1/2) X^2 Z + (1/2) Y + (1/2) Z^3 : X) \, .
\end{align*}
The LMFDB page states that $\operatorname{End}(\operatorname{Jac}(C')) \cong \mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\right]$, in agreement with our computations.

Comment: Is it difficult to determine what is map in $End(C)$ which corresponds to $(-1+\sqrt{5})/2$ ?

Comment: I don't think there is a corresponding endomorphism of $C$, but rather of $J$. But then the question becomes how you want to represent elements of $J$. The matrix I gave in the answer tells you how the map acts on the complex torus $J(\mathbb{C})$ with respect to a choice of basis.

Comment: Let $φ$ be an isogeny corresponding to $(-1+\sqrt{5})/2$. Is it possible to calculate  pull back of given differential $ω$, namely, $φ^*ω$ ?