# Endmorphism $φ$ of genus $2$ curve which satisfies $φ^2+φ-1=0$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Let hyper elliptic curve $C$ be given by equation $C: y^2=x^6+2x^5+x^4-6x^3+2x^2-4x+1$.

It is known by general theory that every autmorphism of $C$ is given by $φ: (x,y)\mapsto(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d},\frac{(ad-bc)y}{(cx+d)^3})$, $a,b,c,d \in\overline　{\Bbb{Q}}$.

I want to find an endmorphism $φ$ of $C$ which satisfies **$φ^2+φ-1=0$**.
So what I should do is just to find $(a,b,c,d)$.
But Equation of $C$ is not factorable anymore, so straightforward calculation seems almost impossible for human.
Using computer or result only is welcomed, thank you for your help.

P.S.
I posted very similar question with typos. Sorry and **thank you so much for people comment or answer to that**, but the typos was too severe, I reposted this question.

Comment: I think you have a misconception about the answer to your question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4624060). The map $\varphi$ there is not an endomorphism of $C$, but rather of the Jacobian of $C$. As you can see [on the LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/Genus2Curve/Q/48841/a/48841/1), $C$ has only two automorphisms (even over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$), namely the identity map and the hyperelliptic involution.

Comment: Thank you so much for a helpful comment. Could you tell me why the curve has only two automorphisms？

Comment: I was just reading what it says on that webpage, but [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139358/reference-for-hyperelliptic-curves) looks helpful. Magma also has the commands `AutomorphismGroup` and `GeometricAutomorphismGroup`. In this example, ```> GeometricAutomorphismGroup(C);
Symmetric group acting on a set of cardinality 2
Order = 2```

Comment: @Viltor Vaughn. Doesn't you answer contradict with Dietrich Burde's answer ?

Comment: Did they actually check that the map they wrote down gives a morphism $C \to C$? It doesn't look like it to me. That post seems to assume that such a map $\varphi$ exists and then derive conditions on the coefficients. But that is not a proof that such a map exists.

Comment: I think they've actually shown that such a $\varphi$ does not exist. For instance, letting $r$ be a root of $x^2 + x - 1$, the first case they give yields the map $(x,y) \mapsto (rx, ry)$. This doesn't take points of $C$ to points of $C$. For instance, $(-2,9)$ is a point of $C$, but $(-2r,9r)$ is not. I haven't checked the second case, but I doubt it gives a map $C \to C$ either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi$ be the map
$$(x,y)\mapsto \left(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d},\frac{(ad-bc)y}{(cx+d)^3}\right)$$
and assume that it is an automorphism of $C$ satisfying
$\phi^2+\phi-{\rm id}=0$. This quadratic condition immediately implies that $b=c=0$, and then the computation is very easy (and "possible for human"), and gives
\begin{align*}
0 & = a^2 + ad - d^2,\\
0 & = a^2 + ad^2 - d^4,
\end{align*}
with $a,d\neq 0$. The solutions of these two equations are given by either $a^2+a-1=0$ and $d=1$, or $a=d+d^2$ and $d^2 + 3d + 1=0$.

Edit: Now we can check explicitly whether or not these four maps are automorphisms of $C$ or not.

Comment: It looks like you've assumed that such a map $\varphi$ exists, and then derived necessary conditions that the coefficients $a,b,c,d$ must satisfy. But are these conditions actually sufficient? Do they result in a map $C \to C$?

Comment: @ViktorVaughn Indeed, I just use the given map. The OP wanted a computation with $\phi$
 and claimed "so straightforward calculation seems almost impossible for human". My answer shows that it is indeed possible. But you are right, I didn't look at the question whether or not this really defines an automorphism of $C$. But anyway, with the explicit solutions obtained, e.g., $d=1$ and two possible values of $a$ etc., we can just check directly.

Comment: Sorry for misleading of my question, thank you so much for both of you.

Comment: @dandelion There is no reason to be sorry (just don't delete next time, but edit). Now you see that there is also a direct computational way to check such things. This is sometimes useful to verify the theoretical results.